# Group rows with the same type from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables `questions`, `answers` and `questions_answers`:

questions:

```
id | question | type_id
1  | Q1       | 1
2  | Q2       | 3
3  | Q3       | 1
4  | Q4       | 2
```

answers:

```
id | answer 
1  | A1
2  | A2
3  | A3
```

questions_answers:

```
id | question_id | answer_id
1  | 1           | 1
2  | 2           | 3
3  | 3           | 1
```

I want to fetch all the questions and group them using `type_id`.

This query groups all the questions but no clue which question belongs to which type:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(q.question, a.answer) FROM questions q
JOIN questions_answers qa ON qa.question_id = q.id
JOIN answers a ON qa.answer_id = a.id
GROUP BY q.id
```

Is it possible to filter the questions by type without multiple joins to the `questions` table?

Output is something I could filter to get each question by `type_id` i.e.:

```
question | answer
Q1       | A1
Q3       | A1
```

This is for `type_id = 1`. Can I get all of them filtered by `type_id` like that? So I can know whci questions belongs to which `type_id`?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: Do you want to filter them by `type_id` or group them by `type_id`? It's not the same thing, and you say both in the question.

Comment: You can use `GROUP BY q.id, q.type_id`

Comment: I updated the description hope it explains what I seek

Comment: I want to get the question and answer grouped by the `type_id` so I can display questions for `type_id =1` in a section and then display only questions with `type_id = 1` in another section

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use the join else you'll end up with a question and no answer.  The query below show's this, selecting Questions where the ***type_id is 1***

```
SELECT 
    q.question 
FROM 
    questions q
WHERE
    q.type_id = 1
```

You can still add WHERE clause to your current statement however, and this will filter the data.  Example below will get all Q & A's again where ***type_id is 1***

```
SELECT 
    q.type_id,
    q.question, 
    a.answer
FROM 
    questions q
    JOIN questions_answers qa 
        ON qa.question_id = q.id
    JOIN answers a 
        ON qa.answer_id = a.id
WHERE
    q.type_id = 1
ORDER BY
    q.type_id
```

Comment: Is it possible without `where`?

Comment: You can't filter without a where clause.  A WHERE keyword is the conditional statement you provide to say _filter the data on this condition_.  If you wanted to output them in an particular order, you could use _ORDER BY_.  See my revised answer